# Intellisense support for writing XPath expressions in Visual studio 2012

Tags: xslt, visual-studio-2012, xpath

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and have created a XSLT-File. When I am editing this file I am getting Intellisense for the XSL Namespace. But when I write an Xpath query for example for `xsl:apply-templates select="//Invoices/Invoice"` I get no Intellisense support for the Xpath query.

How can I achieve Intellisense support for Xpath queries while editing an XSLT document in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not provide much of Intellisense when editing XSLT, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for details, all you get is a completion for template names, template modes, parameter names. You will need to consider XML IDEs like Stylus Studio or Oxygen for better XSLT editing support.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thank you for the prompt answer.